# CMake Error: The source directory "/home/name/Downloads" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt

Tags: ubuntu, cmake

I want to install Gromacs, and I've followed the steps from this [site](https://bioinformaticsreview.com/20151126/how-to-install-gromacs-5-x-x-on-linux-ubuntu-14-04-lts/) until the part where it tells me to enter this command:

> sudo cmake .. -DGMX_BUILD_OWN_FFTW=OFF -DREGRESSIONTEST_DOWNLOAD=OFF -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc -DREGRESSIONTEST_PATH= "PUT YOUR PWD PATH HERE WITHOUT QUOTES"/Downloads/regressiontests-5.1.1

Take note that I am in this directory:

> name@myname:~/Downloads/gromacs-5.1.1/build$

and this is what I entered in the terminal:

> sudo cmake .. -DGMX_BUILD_OWN_FFTW=OFF -DREGRESSIONTEST_DOWNLOAD=OFF -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc -DREGRESSIONTEST_PATH= /home/name/Downloads/regressiontests-5.1.1

but this error message appeared:

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:55 (include):
>     include could not find load file:
>
> gmxVersionInfo
>
> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:64 (include):
>     include could not find load file:
>
> gmxBuildTypeReference
>
> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:65 (include):
>     include could not find load file:
>
> gmxBuildTypeProfile
>
> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:66 (include):
>     include could not find load file:
>
> gmxBuildTypeTSAN
>
> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:67 (include):
>     include could not find load file:
>
> gmxBuildTypeASAN
>
> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:68 (include):
>     include could not find load file:
>
> gmxBuildTypeMSAN
>
> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:69 (include):
>     include could not find load file:
>
> gmxBuildTypeReleaseWithAssert
>
> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:101 (include):
>     include could not find load file:
>
> gmxCPackUtilities
>
> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:102 (gmx_cpack_init):
>     Unknown CMake command "gmx_cpack_init".
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
>   See also "/home/name/Downloads/gromacs-5.1.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

Please help!

Comment: Missed files are contained in `cmake/` subdirectory. Check that the archive you have downloaded contains that directory and these files (with `.cmake` extension). BTW, how the **question's title** is related with the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have a space between `=` and `/` here: `-DREGRESSIONTEST_PATH= /home/name/Downloads/regressiontests-5.1.1`. Remove the space and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @thomas_f answer, Make sure you put the pwd directory pointing to your regressiontests containing folder and the regressiontests version is correct or compatible with your gromacs version. Now gromacs 5.1.1 build in ubuntu 14.x and WSL ubuntu can be simplified by  following the guide in this [BioInformatic-Review](https://bioinformaticsreview.com/20151126/how-to-install-gromacs-5-x-x-on-linux-ubuntu-14-04-lts/). I've successfully build gromacs 5.1.1 on WSL Ubuntu by following the guide.